# how to create udf in ms sql which performs group_concat in operation in mysql for generic table not for specific table

Tags: sql-server-2008

how to create udf in mssql which performs group_concat() operation in mysql for generic table not for specific table...

I tried it in this way but its not working for generic table(any table column)

```
 CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GROUP_CONCAT](
    @tableColumn varchar(max),
    @separator varchar(max)
    )
    returns varchar(max)
    as
    begin
    declare @concatResult varchar(max)
    select @concatResult =STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT @separator + CAST( @tableColumn AS varchar) 
    From ?
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
    return @concatResult
    end;
```